# iOS application have multiple main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading, user-interface

Can we create multiple main thread in single application?
Why all UI changes made in main thread?

I have faced these question in interviews. I am unable to find any solution. Can any one help me to find the answers of this question? That will help me in future interviews and implementations in iOS app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is only one main thread for the application that is created by system for application. Main thread is the thread that directly gives changes to user. Thread which is directly connect with user you can said.

Check the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_main_queue), It states,

> The main queue is automatically created by the system and associated with your application’s main thread. Your application uses one (and only one) of the following three approaches to invoke blocks submitted to the main queue:
>
> - Calling dispatch_main
> - Calling UIApplicationMain (iOS) or NSApplicationMain (OS X)
> - Using a CFRunLoopRef on the main thread
>
> As with the global concurrent queues, calls to dispatch_suspend,
>   dispatch_resume, dispatch_set_context, and the like have no effect
>   when used with queues returned by this function.

Now, let's take an example, If you are downloading an image and want to display it to user. Now if you will download it on main thread then it will block other `UI` till it completed download. So, you should not download it on main thread or synchronously . you should download it asynchronously and when download is completed, you should display it to user on `main thread`, so it will quick displayed to user after download is completed.

Answer (score 3):

There is only ever one main thread in your application, however tasks from multiple dispatch queues *may* execute on this thread. Tasks that are dispatched on the main queue are guaranteed to run on the main thread.

Generally with GCD you do not think about threads, but rather queues which are abstracted from the underlying threads. They provide a level of abstraction that makes it easier to manage tasks without being concerned about the number or state of the threads that are being used.

THe autolayout engine performs a number of calculations and applies rules in order to arrive at a layout solution. If the properties of a UI element change then the autolayout solution is invalidated and needs to be recalculated.

As the main queue is a serial dispatch queue, dispatching UI updates onto the main queue ensures that either the autolayout calculations are being performed *or* a UI property is being updated but not both at the same time (of course there are more than just these two activities happening on the main queue, but we are just addressing autolayout here)